# How to set initial 'rows per page' value in Vuetify DataTable component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**Notice:** The original answer was asked for Vuetify 1.5.7, but API was changed in major releases.

For **Vuetify 1.X** use [the accepted answer by stdob--](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411215/9275224).

For **Vuetify 2.X** use [answer by Tim Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59872426/9275224) or [explanation by greensin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73461020/9275224).

---

I have a page with Vuetify DataTable component (Vuetify 1.5.7) and using default component's pagination. I set the 'Rows per page' select values using the :rows-per-page-items property.

Now I want to set initial value from this rows-per-page-items array (**not only the first one!**) when entering the page.

Is it possible and how can I do this?

Example code of table is shown below:

```js
<v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="equipment"
            class="elevation-1"
            :rows-per-page-items='[15, 30, 50, 100]'>
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `pagination.sync` to control pagination:

```
<v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="equipment"
            class="elevation-1"
            :rows-per-page-items="[15, 30, 50, 100]"
            :pagination.sync="pagination">
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      </template>
</v-data-table>
...
data() {
  return {
    pagination: {
      rowsPerPage: 30
    }, ...
  }
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/95yf1xe8/ ]

Comment: how do i add the "All" option to the rows-per-page-item?

Answer (score 25):

In case someone runs into this but wants it for vuetify 2

It has changed to use the footer-props

```
:footer-props="{'items-per-page-options':[15, 30, 50, 100, -1]}"
```

with -1 for all

See the api in [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-table)
with the footer props in the `v-data-footer` component of the tables api.

Answer (score 8):

This is the current interface as of version 2.3.4+:

```
<v-data-table
   ....
   :footer-props="{'items-per-page-options':[2,15, 30, 50, 100, -1]}"
   :options="options">
   ....
</v-data-table>
...
data() {
  return {
    options: {
      itemsPerPage: 100
    }, ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The API had changed since the answer was accepted. And it DOES NOT work in `Vuetify 2`, with `Vue 2`

The current way to update the footer currently active items shown per page in the footer and the options to select from the drop down is via the `footer-props` property on the `v-data-table` element. and within it an object utilizing the property of `items-per-page-options` like so:

```
<v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items"
            :items-per-page="50"
            :footer-props="{ "items-per-page-options": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, -1]}"
        ></v-data-table>
```

Of course you can feel free to take `"items-per-page-options": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, -1]` value and move it to a data property, same with `items-per-page` value. And of course customize it to any numeric value you want to filter the rows to.

- `-1` - is to provide the "give me all data entires" option
- In my case i desired to present `50` items per page, and display the active size `50` in the footer `"Rows per page ..."` dropdown as well as have custom page sizes options including all option to select via the dropdown. I achieved it via the above code, tested and saw that it is working today(date in the answer)

Enjoy :)

Example from the data table that shows it
[image]

Comment: The original question was asked specifically for Vuetify 1.5.7, so of course API could be changed between major releases. I don't think I need to re-accept answer according to current stable version cause it can confuse developers that uses Vuetify 1.X. Thank you for your answer, but what's the difference between your and most-voted answer by Tim Hall?

Comment: @AlexanderShkirkov

Your post dues to SEO pops up first when searching google on how to achieve this with the latest API. So I believe the right thin to do is expand on that and re-accept an answer that is the way the API works currently to help numerous people visiting this link expecting to find "the-right-way" to achieve this fast via SO.

I believe it would benefit the community if you would do so, but again it is your call :)

Comment: @AlexanderShkirkov My answer is more detailed and helpful in my opinion. But I really don't care which answer you accept :). My goal was to help prevent what happend to me when I reached this link searching google for the way to do this in Vuetify and try help the community.

Comment: Oh, I see. I still think I shouldn't change the accepted answer (you can always use Trending sort to see the most actual answers), but I've added a short notice with an explanation and links to the answers. Thanks for the note!

Comment: Refs https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props

Answer (score 1):

This is the current solution for Vuetify 2.3+.

## Single component:

```
<v-data-table
  :items-per-page="10"
  :footer-props="{ 'items-per-page-options': [10, 50, 100, -1] }"
/>
```

## Overriding globally:

It is possible to override the `default` property on a component's property:

```
import VDataFooter from 'vuetify/lib/components/VDataIterator/VDataFooter';

VDataFooter.options.props.itemsPerPageOptions.default = () => [10, 50, 100, -1];
```

This will prevent you from having to set the footer props every time you render a `<v-data-table />`.

### Nuxt.js edition

Add the following file **vuetify-defaults.js** to your `plugins` directory:

```
import VDataFooter from 'vuetify/lib/components/VDataIterator/VDataFooter';

export default () => {
  VDataFooter.options.props.itemsPerPageOptions.default = () => [10, 50, 100, -1];
};
```

Now in your **nuxt.js.config** file, add the file to your `plugins` array:

```
{
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vuetify-defaults.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone runs into this but wants it for the latest vuetify 2

It has changed to use camel Casing `itemsPerPageOptions` from the old kebab casing items-per-page-options

```js
:footer-props="{'itemsPerPageOptions':[15, 30, 50, 100, -1]}"
```