# How to get vuetify data-table selected itemsPerPage in 2.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to get the selected items-per-page on a Vuetify data-table. It seems some breaking changes have been made. I followed this example:
[How to set initial 'rows per page' value in Vuetify DataTable component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410879/how-to-set-initial-rows-per-page-value-in-vuetify-datatable-component)

Which uses

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="equipment"
        class="elevation-1"
        :rows-per-page-items="[15, 30, 50, 100]"
        :pagination.sync="pagination">
```

And

```
data() {
return {
    pagination: {
      rowsPerPage: 30
    }, ...
  }
}
```

To get the currently-selected `rowsPerPage`. This prints an error like so:
`[BREAKING] 'pagination' has been removed, use 'options' instead. For more information, see the upgrade guide https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0#user-content-upgrade-guide`

I looked through the upgrade guide and there was very little there in the way of footer control of pagination, or how to sync the selected rows-per-page now. I tried using `options` and looking through the code for the table here:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTable.ts#L151

However it's very unclear how to retrieve the selected itemsPerPage, and the `options` don't seem to work as a reactive prop when setting itemsPerPage. If anyone is aware of the current way to do the equivalent of pagination.sync, it'd be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set items per page and rows per page using **vuetify 2.x**

Here is the approach, use the below property in data table component

```
:items-per-page="5"
```

> you can  set items per page as number directly or assign to data reactivity property and
>   dynamically update
>
> also rows per page, add this property to data table

:footer-props="footerProps"

**In script**

```
data(){
  return {
    footerProps: {'items-per-page-options': [15, 30, 50, 100]},
  }
}
```

> Find the working codepen here:

https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/gOOGPdR?editors=1010

**Working code:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
      :footer-props="footerProps"
      @update:items-per-page="getItemPerPage"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      footerProps: {'items-per-page-options': [5, 10,15, 30, 50, 100]},
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getItemPerPage(val) {
      console.log(val);
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi @ chans, thanks for the response. I'm still on clear, how do I get the currently-selected amount? `:itemsPerPage` seems to set the default amount, but if the selected amount changes I want to know what it was changed to.

Comment: Yes it is possible to get the value changed, check the latest codepen changes

Comment: @zavtra, does the above changes in answer resolved your isssue?

Comment: Hey, that worked! Could you post the code changes in your answer? (Codepen doesn't keep snippets as long as needed)

Comment: Upvoted. But where did you find the documentation for this? On the vuetify website the `footer-props` prop is not well documented, just listed —or maybe I just didn't see it?

Answer (score 3):

Easy way:
`:footer-props="{ itemsPerPageOptions: [25,50,100,-1]}"`
Note that -1 is for add 'All' to the options

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who, like me, was looking for the new option to show all rows by default, it has now changed (- working in v2.2.11):

**Old way**

```
:pagination.sync="{ rowsPerPage: -1 }"
```

**New way**

```
:items-per-page="-1"
```

Not sure if items and rows are used interchangeably but this caught me out for a while.